# Why Angular HttpClient maps the string array from json to object array?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I don't have enough experience in TypeScript thus the following behavior looks unexpectedly for me.

1. Please, explain to me why it is happening?
2. Also, I would like to know what the best practices exist allow to avoid such problems.

There is the following dto:

```
export class Data {
    public id: string;
    public uri: string;
    public title: string;
    public description: string;
    public contentPreviewLinks: string[] = [];
}
```

The Angular HttpClient fetching data from a server (example from the Dev console Network Response):

```
{
  "id": "971530ed-d06b-4217-9036-a267add57784",
  "uri": "qwerty",
  "title": "Example",
  "description": null,
  "contentPreviewLinks": [
    "http://example.com/img1.jpg",
    "http://example.com/img2.jpg",
    "http://example.com/img3.jpg"
  ]
}
```

The requested HttpClient code:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    public get(uri: string): Observable<Data> {
        return this.http.get<Data>(HttpRoutes.DATA.replace(/{uri}/, uri));
    }
}
```

The response postprocessing:

```
const validLinks = this.data.contentPreviewLinks.filter(item => ObjectUtil.isNotBlank(item));
```

**Expected behavior**: that items from the contentPreviewLinks mapped to the dto as strings.
**Actual behavior**: items from the contentPreviewLinks mapped to the dto as objects. The following logs from the console confirm it:
[image: console logs]

**UPD:** The problem was cloning the response incorrectly (it code was not presented here).

Comment: Can you please post your `HttpClient` code? including the snippet where you `console.log`

Comment: @Zze I've posted the requested client code, please, have a look

Comment: Is `HttpRoutes.DATA` either `null` or `undefined` ? From what has been posted I am not really sure what the issue you are currently having is.. i.e. posted code looks fine. I suspect it is either deeper or something is missing a value / null

Comment: @Zze yes you are absolutely right! I've found the cause of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working - you should post your solve as an answer for completeness :)